# Head-on collision of $\rm N_2$ and $\rm CO_2$ molecules

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, acoustics, spectroscopy, molecules

Consider a standing sound wave formed in the air in conditions close to standard pressure and temperature in the antinode region. On the molecular level, it will involve multiple collisions of air particles moving in the opposite direction. This includes head-on collision of collinear $\rm N_2$ and $\rm CO_2$ molecules. Consider this system in the center of the mass frame. The kinetic energy of colliding particles causes compression of interatomic bonds. When the bonds absorb the energy, they will be elevated to a higher quantized vibrational state.   The $\rm CO_2$ oxygen atom further away from the center of collision will be compressed less, resulting in the formation of the asymmetric stretch which is IR active. According to Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon-dioxide_laser
N2 {v1(1)} and CO2{V3(1)} are nearly perfectly resonant. A slight eccentricity of collision would change the rotational mode as well. Those collisions will probably meet the selection rule leading to the emission of photons. Is it true?

Comment: "According to Wikipedia": can you [edit] your question to link to what you're reading? I don't generally think of Wikipedia as a place for data on the details of molecular spectra. I would also expect the rotational states to be excited before the vibrational states. If the molecules have nonzero orbital angular momentum, your assumption of a "co-linear" collision becomes unreasonable.

Comment: What I proposed is a first approximation. I understand that my question can be answered by applying Molecular Dynamics (MD) which rigorously characterizes the molecular collision of gases with a thoroughly validated fully atomistic (FA) model incorporating bonded and non-bonded interactions verified by an experiment.

Comment: Not really. The answer can provide a computer simulation or even better relatively simple test.